# Que me falta para completar mi comando y me pueda tambien mostrar area_id

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Esta es mi base de datos][image: Este es el resultado que me esta dando]Este es el metodo que estoy usando en el index para traer los id de las tablas respectivas respectivas

```
public function index(Request $request)
        {
            return $child= EquipmentChild::
                leftjoin('equipment','equipment_children.equipment_id','=','equipment.id')
                ->select('equipment_children.*','equipment_children.name','equipment.machinery_id')
                 ->get();
```

[image: Esto es el resultado, pero quiero area_id]

Comment: Un JOIN con `machineries` por el machinery_id y añades el campo en el select, no?

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias